Dealing with non-stationary time series in Granger Causality
I am working on determining the Granger Causality of two time series.
One thing to note is that for my specific project, I have around 100k time series across two different dimensions, say Product Name and Sales Type, and I am trying to determine if different Sales Types granger cause one particular Sales Type.
In my analysis thus far, I have smoothed the time series by taking the exponential moving average and then normalized it by looking at day-over-day change in the exponential moving average. I will be looking at granger causality for the day-over-day change in the exponential moving average for different sales types for each product name.
Theoretically, I believe the day-over-day change is already a form of differencing, so presumably, this should force the time series to be stationary. That said, I've run an ADF test and around 10% of my time series are non-stationary with a threshold of 0.05.
I am wondering how to proceed, since I don't want to change the interpretation too much by doing another round of normalization. Two questions arise:

Is it ok to just toss out all the non-stationary time series?
Since the exponential moving average introduces autocorrelation into the series, could this be why my series are non-stationary?

Forgive my ignorance in this area, I am just trying to reach a reasonable next step.
